# extjs 4 store is undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I'm creating a simple store in coffeescript but it returns as undefined when I call it in the browser console `Ext.getStore('visitors')`

```
Ext.define 'heroico.store.Visitors',
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store'
    model: 'heroico.model.Visitor'
    storeId: 'visitors'
```

If I create it without actually extending `'Ext.data.Store'` I can find it via `getStore` method but then I can't load it in my controller in the `stores` array:

```
Ext.create 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'heroico.model.Visitor'
    storeId: 'visitors'
```

Any idea why it would behave this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controllers automatically initialize stores.  If you have it in your controller's stores array and it isn't getting loaded, make sure your controller is getting loaded by listing it in your controllers array in Application.js.  Also make sure you are correctly listing it in your stores array, you didn't post that code.  Check the console for any errors.

Comment: I don't know why this one got downvoted because it contains the solution. My controller loading the stores was not mentioned in the app `controllers`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Ext.define` only defines a class, it does not create an instance of that class. So when you call `Ext.getStore` it returns `null`.

After defining your store, make sure to call `Ext.create('heroico.store.Visitors')` somewhere to actually create an instance, then `Ext.getStore` should work.